# Enable IPv6 on docker image for Bitwarden

Tags: docker, ipv6

How do I enable IPv6 support when running Bitwarden from its Docker image? I changed /etc/docker/daemon.json as follows bit Bitwarden is still not reachable via IPv6:

```
{
  "log-level": "warn",
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "5"
  },
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64"
}
```

I am not sure if "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64" is correct, though.

Do I need to change anything else?

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure if "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64" is correct,
> though.

"2001:db8:1::/64" is incorrect, that is in a [documentation prefix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3849). Substitute your own (globally scoped) /64.